# DXA Custom Controller Issue (Routing)

Tags: dxa, web8, mvc

I am trying to create a custom controller for a taxonomy keywords navigation module in DXA1.4 .Net; however, I always hit the same error:

**The controller for path '/taxonomy/test' was not found or does not implement IController.**

I have declared my Module:Controller in the Component Template
[image: Component Template]

And this relates to the Controller in my project, which I deploy to my Site for testing:

[image: Solution Screenshot]

I deploy the Controllers to the Site in a DLL by using the xcopy function, but I am sure this is not the issue here.

My ViewModel is registered as follows:

[image: ViewModel Registration]

And my Controller is shown here:

[image]

Please let me know if you need more info...

Thank you for taking the time to look.

**Add on information:**

When I run the site in Visual Studio we get the following break at the Main view (detailed in my Component Template MetaData) at the Html.DxaEntities() method.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a route to the NavigationTaxonomyController defined in Global.asax.cs ?

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for responding.  No I didn't and I am not sure how to do this as I do not see a Global.asax.cs in the DXA project.  Do I need to create the class and do you have an example of the route please?

Comment: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Global.asax.cs

Comment: Is the update of the Global.asax.cs file something new? We have in the training where we create a custom controller in our new module and there is no need for us to update the Global.asax.cs for this to work.

Comment: Indeed, Entity Controllers don't have to be registered explicitly in Global.asax.cs; that's taken care of by `BaseAreaRegistration`, I was just wondering where the URL path came from (since it doesn't seem to match the name of a controller nor action).

Comment: That is what i thought as well, thanks. We too are tying to figure out where the URL path is coming from as well since it isn't matching the controller nor action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that (part of) the problem is that your controller classes are not explicitly declared as `public` (and the default visibility for classes is `internal` in C#).

I also don't understand why the URL path in the error message is `/taxonomy/test`; the (virtual) URL path for Entity Controllers registered in [`BaseAreaRegistration`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Configuration/BaseAreaRegistration.cs) is in format `/{controller}/{action}`, so it seems that is trying to invoke the `test` action/method on the `taxonomy` controller (TaxonomyController) for some reason.

Comment: I just noticed that the classes were not public. I have made them public now and rebuilt the solution and now i am getting the following Error:

2016-07-29 17:15:27,041 [8] ERROR - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Taxonomy.Providers.KeywordProvider.RetrieveKeywords(String categoryId)
   at Taxonomy.Controllers.NavigationTaxonomyController.EnrichModel(ViewModel model)

Comment: So apparently your NavigationTaxonomyController now gets invoked successfully, but there is a problem in its implementation.  Sounds like the original problem has been solved.

Comment: The shifting of the classes to public has allowed the controllers to get invoked, The error message I fixed, it turns out the schema fields it was looking for the casing was wrong. It seems to be working now. Thanks!