# Custom Navigation Controller Routing Issue

Tags: dxa

I have created a custom Navigation controller for breadcrumb under the `Navigations` folder of my project module (DXA 1.7 .NET). However, I am getting the below error on every page:

> The controller for path "requested page url" was not
>   found or does not implement IController

Here is the Compoent Template:
[image]

Here is the Project Structure:

[image]

I have added the entry in project Area Registration:

```
RegisterViewModel("Breadcrumb", typeof(NavigationLinks), "Navigations");
```

Also here is the code for the `NavigationsController`:

```
public class NavigationsController : NavigationController
{
    public override ActionResult Navigation(EntityModel entity, string navType, int containerSize = 0)
    {
        if (navType.Trim().ToLower() == "topmenu")
        {
            SitemapItem model = SiteConfiguration.NavigationProvider.GetNavigationModel(WebRequestContext.Localization);
            EntityModel sourceModel = (EnrichModel(entity) as EntityModel) ?? entity;
            model.XpmMetadata = sourceModel.XpmMetadata;
            model.XpmPropertyMetadata = sourceModel.XpmPropertyMetadata;
            return View(sourceModel.MvcData.ViewName, model);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Navigation(entity, navType, containerSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the entry in `Global.asax`

```
// Navigation JSON
routes.MapRoute(
    "Core_Navigation",
    "navigation.json",
    new { controller = "Navigations", action = "SiteMapJson" }
).DataTokens.Add("area", "XXX");
routes.MapRoute(
    "Core_Navigation_loc",
     "{localization}/navigation.json",
     new { controller = "Navigations", action = "SiteMapJson" }
).DataTokens.Add("area", "XXX");
```

Please suggest If I have missed anything here? I am not sure why it is showing the Page URL in the error message? I have looked into a similar issue ([DXA Custom Controller Issue (Routing)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/dxa-custom-controller-issue-routing)) posted on stack previously, but its scenario is different.

Here is the full `StackTrace` :

> `
>   StackTrace " at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func1 func)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues)\r\n   at
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize)\r\n   at
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, Int32 containerSize)\r\n   at
>   ASP._Page_Areas_XXX_Views_Region_BreadcrumbContainer_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\D\Projects\XXX\WebSite-SouceCode\XXX\Areas\XXX\Views\Region\BreadcrumbContainer.cshtml:line
>   2\r\n   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()\r\n 
>   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)"
>   string

`

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Why do you change the routes for `navigation.json` in `Global.asax` ? It seems your custom navigation controller doesn't override the `SiteMapJson` action?

Comment: @RickPannekoek,  I have added the StackTrace.

Comment: Try putting your Controller in the same namespace as your AreaRegistration class.

Comment: Oh. I will try that and confirm.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, thanks a lot. It is now working. Please add your suggestion as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC use a bit of magic to find Controller classes.  By default, it assumes that Controllers are in the same namespace as the `AreaRegistration` class (or a sub namespace).

Given your project structure, it seems this is not the case and hence the Controller cannot be found. You could change the namespace of your Controller or AreaRegistration class.

Alternatively, you can add namespaces to the `AreaRegistrationContext`. See, for example: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Configuration/BaseAreaRegistration.cs